adobe illustrator cep undo stack
In Adobe Illustrator, when working with a CEP (Common Extensibility Platform) panel that modifies TextFrame objects and dispatches events, all these changes should be grouped under a single entry in the undo history. Currently, each modification, whether it's a TextFrame change or an event dispatch, creates a separate entry in the undo stack. This results in multiple undo actions for what is conceptually a single operation.

InDesign has app.doScript() method exactly for this purpose. But Illustrator hasn't, as far as I know. I don't know if it's possible in Illustrator.
